# Composable annotation in android jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am working on a multimodule project with three modules `Core`, `A` and `B`. Both modules `A` and `B` uses `Core`. There is a screen (or composable) in module `B` that I need to reuse in module `A`. I can just move that screen to `Core` but I don't think this is scalable. So I am defining an `Interface` in `Core` whose implementation would be provided by `B`. Then `A` will get that `Interface` through DI and use it without dealing with it's implementation.

```
interface NotificationLayout {
    @Composable
    fun NotificationLayoutStatusState(
        modifier: Modifier,
    )
}
```

This will be implemented by `B`. But when I run it, it just crashes with `NoSuchMethodError`

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No interface method NotificationLayoutStatusState(Landroidx/compose/ui/Modifier;Landroidx/compose/runtime/Composer;I)V
```

Can anyone please help me. I think this has to do with the `Composable` annotation.

Comment: I don't know how to solve your problem, but in terms of architecture I would create a new module, something like `SharedViews`.

Comment: I have thought that but sharing a view means, sharing ViewModel, state class and almost everything. I think this might result in god modules. So, I am trying to use dependency inversion to keep the view code to it's own module and only sharing a contract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to enable compose(i.e not only adding the compose dependencies) in all the modules that use the interface. Previously I was only enabling compose in modules `A` and `B` but not in `core` and that was causing the issue.